# Call a method from my @httpPost

Tags: rest

I may @restresource I wan to call another method from my @httpPost. Is it possible. When I try I am getting error : `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: xmlReader(String)` Is there any way to call a method from @httpost because I don't wan to code whole thing in a single method I want it to be separated. 
My code :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Lead')
global with sharing class ParentRest {
@HttpPost
global static Lead doPost() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    system.debug('The request ' + req);
    system.debug('Request Body in Blob : ' + req.requestBody );
    Blob reqBlob = req.requestBody;
    system.debug('Request Body in String : ' + reqBlob.toString() );
    xmlReader(reqBlob.toString());
    //system.debug('Request ContentType : ' + req.params.get('Address1'));
    return null;
}


global string xmlReader(String stringXml){

    return null;
}  
}
```

Please help me if there any possible way to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access the `xmlReader` method as it is an instance method, and your `@HttpPost` method is static.

You would need to make the `xmlReader` method static, or instantiate a `ParentRest` class to access it.

```
global static string xmlReader(String stringXml){

    return null;

}
```

or

```
...
system.debug('Request Body in String : ' + reqBlob.toString() );
ParentRest pr = new ParentRest();
pr.xmlReader(reqBlob.toString());
//system.debug('Request ContentType : ' + req.params.get('Address1'));
...
```

You can read more about Static and Instance in Apex here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_static.htm

Comment: yes thanks. It works. But may I know y such. In others it is works when we call a method like this. In this case case we need to create a instantiate of class and then call the method. My know the reason for this.

Comment: If you follow the link that I included with the answer as it sounds like you need to read-up and understand the difference between instance vs. static methods in Apex (and programming in general).